# How to send nested json using Axios Vue in Mangodb

Tags: mongodb, express, vue.js, axios

Wanted to send following data in to the mangodb using axios but getting error of 400
{"data":{"name":"cvc","lastname":"cv","gender":"Male","dob":"2020-10-27"}}

```
await this.$axios.$post( 'http://localhost:8000/owner',user,{timeout: 120000 })
        .then(response => {
          this.errors = [];
          this.snackbar = true;
          console.log(response)
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.response)
          this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
          console.log('somthing went wrong')
          if (error.response.status === 400 ){
            console.log(this.errors)
          }
        })
```

Comment: And what response message do you get?

Comment: Error 400 is `Bad Request`. Your frontend sends something wrong to your backend, or at least your backend expects something different. This needs more info, especially from the backend side to see what is actually expected